# Sandboxed calendar app wants access to contacts?

Tags: macos, calendar, contacts, sandbox

My sandboxed OSX App (10.9 Mavericks) can create a calendar and events in the Apple calendar.
What i currently don't understand, why the app wants additional access to contacts, when the app is started?

I am not using any code that is accessing the contacts.
My project does not use the "AddressBook.framework".

Since i have not enabled "Contacts" in the sandbox, i am getting the warning:
Sandboxed app can't access address book without proper entitlements.

I wonder if it is related to the Birthdays calendar.

Comment: Is this 10.9 Mavericks or 10.8? There are some subtle differences between those two sandbox-implementations. As well as your violation might relate to the "Me" Card and calendar invitations.

Comment: I am wondering the same question too. Any ideas?

Comment: I noticed the following. In my "awakeFromNib" i have one line of code that is related to calendars."store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];". If i comment this out, i don't get a warning anymore. So accessing EKEventStore seems to require contacts entitlement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i would like to share an official response from Apples tech support. It's a bug:

> EventKit directly accesses AddressBook in its implementation. You are getting this warning because your app, which is sandboxed, does not have a Contact entitlement that is required for accessing AddressBook. Note that this warning does not prevent you from carrying EventKit operations and this issue is currently being investigated.
>   Please note that this is a known issue that is being investigated.